# Assigning a JavaScript variable value to a JSP integer variable

Tags: javascript, jsp

Can anyone help me on this problem.
I want to assign a JavaScript variable value to a JSP integer variable.Is it possible?
I have tried by myself but its not working.
Basically i want to do something like this.
"var i=10;"
"<% int x %>"
Here i want the value of JavaScript variable "i" to be assigned in JSP variable "x"
Please reply..I am stuck in here.
Advance Thanks.

Comment: what is your actual requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a Java script variable's value to a Java variable. However, the reverse is possible.

If you want, you can send the value in your request (as query string) to pass it on to server.

This is because, JS runs on your browser and JSP on the server. The servlet is executed before the javascript in the browser is executed.

See the [link](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/148220-assign-javascript-variable-java-variable-problem-jsp)

Comment: With the risk of being nit-picky, you cannot "assign" the value of a java (server-side) variable to a javascript (client-side) variable. You can, however, render a piece of javascript-code that will, when interpreted and executed by the browser, create a javascript variable and assign it a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done.  The scriplet part <% ... %> is run on the server.  The js part is executed by the browser.
Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you can manipulate the DOM using js.